# Use c pointer to print 2d int array

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, integer, 2d

I'm a c beginner and I've been trying to understand pointers. Specifically, how they can be used like arrays.

```
int main()
{
        int arr[2][3] = { { 0, 1, 2 }, { 3, 4, 5 } };
        int (*aptr)[2][3] = &arr;
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                        printf("%d ", aptr[i][j]);
                }
                printf("\n");
        }
        return 0;
}
```

In this code I'm trying to create a 2d int array, point a pointer at it, then print the array using the pointer. When I compile, I get this error:

```
est.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:21:13: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
   21 |    printf("%d ", aptr[i][j]);
      |            ~^    ~~~~~~~~~~
      |             |           |
      |             int         int *
      |            %ls
```

I know I can print the array very easily without using a pointer at all, I just don't understand why *aptr[i][j]* has type 'int *'.

Answer (score -1):

You declared `aptr` as `int *aptr[2][3]`. Which is a pointer to an array of 2 pointers to an array of 3 pointers `int ***`. So to access `arr[i][j]` from `aptr` you need to deference it `*aptr[i][j]`.

Comment: Re “You declared `aptr` as `int *aptr[2][3]`”: No, they did not. The code says `int (*aptr)[2][3]`, which is different. And using it as `*aptr[i][j]` will not work.